# Call to a member function collect() getting null in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.9

I am using the **iKantam buyback** extension in **Magento 1.9.2** . When I click on the **sell** button from the single product page. It gives me the following **error**:

```
FATAL ERROR: Call to a member function collect() on null in \app\code\community\Ikantam\Buyback\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Nominal.php
```

I want after click event occurs it will redirect to the checkout page with the required values.

Please help me I am stuck.

Comment: Can we see a sample of the `Nominal` code, covering line 48 and surrounding lines? You/readers need to work out why an object initialisation seems to have failed.

Comment: no need.the problem is fixed. Thanks for your concern

Comment: Would you mind, noting a short update in the question, so those that took the time to read your question have an idea, what the cause was? That would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Preeti please explain what you did to solve the issue, so that it can help others who have are having a similar/same issue and find this question from searching.